# defining a variable in a closure or locally, which is faster?

Tags: javascript, closures

I got some basic drawing with canvas with jcanvas going on:

```
this.div.bind("mousedown", function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
        var point= [];
        var pX, pY;
        point[0]= (ev.pageX- this.offsetLeft);
        point[1]= (ev.pageY- this.offsetTop);
        that.div.bind("mousemove", function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            pX= (ev.pageX- this.offsetLeft);
            pY= (ev.pageY- this.offsetTop);
            that.canvas.drawLine({
                strokeStyle: "#000",
                strokeWidth: 10,
                rounded: true,
                x1: point[0], y1: point[1],
                x2: pX, y2: pY,
            });
            point[0]= pX;
            point[1]= pY;
        });

        that.div.bind("mouseup", function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            that.div
                .unbind('mousemove')
                .unbind('mouseup');
        });
    });
```

Noticed that I declared pX and pY in the mousedown event, making them accessible as a closure to the inner function that is bound to the mouseover event. I was wondering what would be faster, declaring them inside the mouseover event or as it is now.

On one hand declaring those two variables outside means there will be less variables allocated when the mouseover event is called (which is a lot of times) on the other hand actually accessing those variables means that I need to look in two different scopes to find them.

I was wondering which operation is slower in Javascript. My intuition says that allocation should be a lot slower, assuming that the Javascript engines use stack-based allocation for local variables, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Isn't this trivial to benchmark yourself?

Comment: check out jsperf.com great site for these sorts of things.

Comment: I was actually planning on benchmarking it myself if no one had greater insight on this matter. I will wait a couple of days, if I got no response i will post my findings here.

Comment: So, on one hand, you have the penalty of creating a local variable (more precisely, a name binding in the current environment record), and on the other hand you have the penalty of accessing the parent scope (environment record). The only way to find out is to benchmark it. You can either do it yourself, or somebody here can do it for you, but I don't think that anybody can know this without benchmarking it. My guess is that variable creation preforms better - especially, since you access the variable multiple times within the handler.